# Magento 2: Mini Cart return no items

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I have a bug with magento 2.1 but i think it is from base.
when i add to cart from product detail: ajax is loaded and everything is good, mini cart show 1 item
but the bug appear when i add to cart from homepage or extension have button not ajax. minicart does not update and return "No items"

Now, miniCart have a trigger call function load minicart after add to cart by ajax so if i code a button add to cart not run ajax but product is added, no wrong. the trigger is not called so minicart return wrong.

Can you fix it in next version of magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed to me when I upgrade my PHP version from 7.0.9 to 7.0.15.

I use this container Docker below with **Apache 2.4 + PHP 7.0.15 + OPCache + MariaDB + Magerun + DevAlias**.

https://hub.docker.com/r/rafaelcgstz/magento2/